# coverting all string[] to int[] and getting rid of the error message

Tags: c#

In the code below i am getting "System.FormatException HResult 
Message=Input string was not in a correct format. Can someone please help me out of this situation. Thanks

```
public static string Str()
{
    string finalNumumber = "";

    // code
    // code
    // code

    foreach (var item in items)
    {                
        finalNummber += item.ToString() + ",";
    }    

    return finalNumumber; // (output here is 3,5,1,8)
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string dnumber = Str();
    int[] a = Array.ConvertAll(dnumber, int.Parse);
}
```

Comment: Where is the string array that you want to convert?

Comment: Putting commas in between letters doesn't make an array

Comment: Your code line with Array.ConvertAll will produce a compiler error, because Array.ConvertAll does **not** accept an argument of type `string`.

Comment: Why does `Str` return `string` rather than `string[]`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're calling `string.Split(',')` on the string to convert it to an array, Your code would leave a training comma.

I.E. the actual string probably is `"3,5,1,8,"`

You'll need to either trim the comma, or add StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries to the `Split()` call. Otherwise, there will be an empty string at the end of the array which will fail to convert.

I.E.

```
string[] dnumber = Str().Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Array.ConvertAll* can accept a string array as first argument, but you pass a string. You need to convert the string to a string array using the *Split* method and then pass that array to *Array.ConvertAll*.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string dnumber = Str();
    string[] strArray = dnumber.Split(',');
    int[] a = Array.ConvertAll(strArray, int.Parse);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Three ways how to do what you want

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string dnumber = Str();
    string[] array = dnumber.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    int[] v1 = Array.ConvertAll(array, s => int.Parse(s));
    int[] v2 = Array.ConvertAll(array, int.Parse);
    int[] v3 = array.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
}
```